# Use Matlab to compare columns in different cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to compare two cell arrays that contain both characters and numbers. I would like to compare two specific columns and then return the values in another related column.

For example, I have two cell arrays of the forms:

```
One=         Two=
[A 2 10      [A 1 2 76
 B 2 11       B 1 2 78
 A 5 22       C 1 2 80
 B 5 23       D 1 4 98
 A 6 28       E 1 4 99
 B 6 28       F 1 4 100
 C 6 28]      G 1 6 110]
```

And I want to be able to find everywhere column 2 of 'One' equals column 3 of 'Two' and return the specific value in column 4 of 'Two.' So for this example, I would obtain a result that is:

```
Three=
[76
 78
 80
 110]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I understand 76, 78, and 110, but I don't understand why the 80 row shows up?  mistake?

Comment: 76, 78, and 80 correspond to a 2 in the third column... which corresponds to the 2 in the second column of 'One'.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: convert to numeric array first

```
X = cell2mat(One(:,2:end));
Y = cell2mat(Two(:,2:end));
result = Y(X(:,1)==Y(:,2),3)
```

Option 2: convert to numeric array at various points

```
result = cell2mat(Two(cell2mat(One(:,2))==cell2mat(Two(:,3)),4))
```

Option 3: convert cell to table first

```
T1 = cell2table(One);
T2 = cell2table(Two);
result = T2.Two4(T1.One2==T2.Two3)
```

Option 4: abuse how Matlab cell arrays and numeric arrays work

```
result = [Two{([One{:,2}]==[Two{:,3}])',4}]'
```

Comment: What if my matrices are of different sizes? Mine often are so I always run into trouble with that.

Comment: @JanaSmith I don't understand what you're asking with this comment. Clarify?

Comment: My cell arrays are different lengths (like 9x1 and 11x1) and Matlab never likes that.